# ForEach List knockout to display in different divs, possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, knockout.js

I have my List that binded to my parentDiv

```html
<div class="parentDivLegende" data-bind="template: {name: 'legende', foreach : ListeLegende}"></div>
```

And for each elements it generates a div, that contains two mo divs, see below:

```html
<script id="legende" type="text/html">
    <div class="PaddingLegende">
        <div class="CircleLegendeColor imgLegende" data-bind="style: { backgroundColor : Couleur}"></div>
        <div data-bind="text: Libelle" class="TextLegende"></div>
    </div>
</script>
```

But, foreach 3 elements, I want to create a new divParent, I want it to look like this:

```html
<div class="parentDivLegende">
            <div class="PaddingLegende">
                <div class="CircleLegendeColor imgLegende" data-bind="style: { backgroundColor : Couleur}"></div>
                <div data-bind="text: Libelle" class="TextLegende"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="PaddingLegende">
                <div class="CircleLegendeColor imgLegende" data-bind="style: { backgroundColor : Couleur}"></div>
                <div data-bind="text: Libelle" class="TextLegende"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="PaddingLegende">
                <div class="CircleLegendeColor imgLegende" data-bind="style: { backgroundColor : Couleur}"></div>
                <div data-bind="text: Libelle" class="TextLegende"></div>
            </div>
</div>
```

Means, starting at 3rd, 7th, 10th etc elements I want it to open a new parent div.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There should be an $index() property accessible in your loop.  You can then use an if binding to determine the index of the loop and change the elements rendered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in your code using `computed`s.

```js
function obj(lib, col) {
  return {
    Libelle: lib,
    Couleur: col
  };
}

data = [
  obj('one', 'blue'),
  obj('two', 'green'),
  obj('three', 'red'),
  obj('four', 'gray'),
  obj('five', 'lightblue'),
  obj('six', 'lightgreen'),
  obj('seven', 'lightgray')
];

vm = (function() {
  var self = {};
  self.originalArray = ko.observable(data);
  self.groupedArray = ko.computed(function() {
    var result = [],
      originalData = self.originalArray();
    for (var index = 0; index < originalData.length; index += 3) {
      result.push(originalData.slice(index, index + 3));
    }
    return result;
  });
  return self;
}());

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="foreach: groupedArray">
  <h1>Group begins</h1>
  <div class="parentDivLegende" data-bind="foreach:$data">
    <div class="PaddingLegende">
      <div class="CircleLegendeColor imgLegende" data-bind="style: { backgroundColor : Couleur}">
        Some color
      </div>
      <div data-bind="text: Libelle" class="TextLegende"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great! But I can't make it work with my piece of code. Could you please take a look [HERE IN JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/c0c7ae38/) ?? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I did it! Thank you Roy! First foreach **groupedArray**, and for second foreach I put my **List**, that why it did not work. Then I replaced it with **$data** --- and there we go!